# Check null or empty data from three columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns and I want to check `Null` or `Empty` data from the columns either its is `Imp` or `Main` or `Comp`.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT Imp,Main,Comp
FROM Items_tbl
WHERE Contributor = 37 
 AND NULLIF(Imp, '') IS NULL
 AND NULLIF(Main, '') IS NULL
 AND NULLIF(Comp, '') IS NULL;
```

Comment: Do you want to select the rows only if all three fields are null?

Comment: What is your question? Does it work as expected? What did you expect?

Comment: @mhn yes ! i want to select the data which is `null` or `empty` from the table

Comment: just remove the NULLIF. it is not required

Comment: Change the IS NULL's in the where to = '' and it will return Nulls or empty string

Comment: @PatrickHofman i am trying to fetch those values which is empty from in the table.

Comment: So you only want to select the data if it is null. That doesn't make sense. The fields will always be null now!

Comment: Your where clause would be ... where Contributor=37 and IMP IS NULL and  Main IS NULL and Comp IS NULL ;

Comment: @mhn that doesn't take `''` into account. The approach of the OP is good, I just think she needs to select the PK or ID of the table also.

Comment: i want to check both null or empty values @mhn

Comment: @NickyvV yes ypu are right

Comment: @GarimaRawat What do you want to do with the results? Because just selecting the 3 `NULL` columns doesn't make any sense. Could you please explain?

Comment: @NickyvV i have a bulk  record  of key wording. where user fill these details. and i want to check those rows which is empty of null from the three columns.

Comment: @GarimaRawat Ok, that is `why` you are doing it. :) Q remains: What are you gonna do with the results? Do you wanna exclude those rows somewhere? Or send a notice to the user? You may want to include another (unique) column in the `SELECT` so you know which rows match the criteria you want.

Comment: @GarimaRawat SO you want result set only all columns are NULL or all columns are empty. Is that right? If one of the columns is not empty then you don't want it in the result set. Please confirm if I have understood it correctly

Comment: @NickyvV i just want to count the number of rows which is not filled by user either it is `imp` or `comp` or `Main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to `COUNT` the rows you could just do the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Items_tbl
WHERE Contributor=37 
 AND NULLIF(Imp, '') IS NULL
 AND NULLIF(Main, '') IS NULL
 AND NULLIF(Comp, '') IS NULL;
```

Or if you only need one of those columns to be `NULL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Items_tbl
WHERE Contributor=37 
 AND (NULLIF(Imp, '') IS NULL
      OR NULLIF(Main, '') IS NULL
      OR NULLIF(Comp, '') IS NULL
     );
```

Comment: thanks the second one is working :D . I really appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment regarding needing a count...

```
SELECT Count(*)
  FROM Items_tbl
 WHERE  Contributor=37 and  ISNULL(Imp, '') = '' 
 and   ISNULL(Main, '') = '' 
 and  ISNULL(Comp, '') = '' ;
```

Comment: this would make sense only if one more column would be selected. like contributor

Comment: @mhn Agreed, I was just responding to OP's question and not assuming they wanted anything they are not asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if I have understood the question correctly, but if you want all the rows where the 3 columns is either NULL/empty, you could try this :

```
SELECT     ID, Contributor,
           Imp,
           Main,
           Comp
FROM       Items_tbl
WHERE      Contributor = 37
AND        (Imp IS NULL OR Imp = '')
AND        (Main IS NULL OR Main = '')
AND        (Comp IS NULL OR Comp = '')
```

You can see this here ->[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dcc8/1)

Note that for this query either all the 3 columns in question should either be all NULL or all empty.

In case, you want all the rows where even one of the aforementioned columns is NULL/empty, you could use a `UNION' to get this as follows :

```
SELECT     ID, Contributor,
           Imp,
           Main,
           Comp
FROM       Items_tbl
WHERE      Contributor = 37
AND        (Imp IS NULL OR Imp = '')
AND        (Main IS NULL OR Main = '')
AND        (Comp IS NULL OR Comp = '')

UNION

SELECT     ID, Contributor,
           Imp,
           Main,
           Comp
FROM       Items_tbl
WHERE      Contributor = 37
AND        (Imp IS NULL)
OR         (Main IS NULL)
OR         (Comp IS NULL)
```

See this here -> [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dcc8/5)

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

**Edit:**

```
SELECT Imp,Main,Comp
    FROM Items_tbl
    WHERE  Contributor=37 AND COALESCE(NULLIF(ISNULL(Imp,''),''),NULLIF(ISNULL(Main,''),''),NULLIF(ISNULL(Comp,''),'')) is NULL
```

Comment: This will not check for all the columns to be `NULL`. Further the `= NULL` doesn't work, and it doesn't make it any more readable.

Comment: there should be is instead =

Comment: And I don't think you need the `ISNULL`'s